# How can I allow IGMP-traffic in Firewalld?

Tags: firewalld

Following a guide, the author allow IGMP-traffic with IPtables with the following line:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p igmp -j ACCEPT
```

But my boss wants me to do it with Firewalld.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've been chasing my tail on this exact same issue, and I stumbled across a bug report filed against firewalld for enabling IGMP during application install. (Credit to the OP here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1048947)

In that the author was kind enough to provide a workaround that does what we need:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p igmp -j ACCEPT
```

Until (or if) a feature is added for enabling IGMP communication in another way, it seems the Direct interface is the best way to apply such rule changes.

Official documentation on the direct interface:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD#Direct_options

Comment: Give the same command again without `--permanent` to have the rule take effect immediately without needing a firewall restart or reboot.

Comment: In the latest versions of CentOS 7, it seems that firewall-cmd will not let you add rules to the INPUT chain, but will silently fail. Use the INPUT_direct chain instead.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to a direct rule, IGMP traffic can also be accepted with either `--add-protocol=igmp` (if your `firewall-cmd` version already supports it) or with the help of a [rich rule](http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.richlanguage.html).

For `firewall-cmd` versions already supporting `--add-protocol=protocol`:

```shell
firewall-cmd --permanent \
             --zone=YOUR-ZONE \
             --add-protocol=igmp

firewall-cmd --reload
```

Effectively this adds the line `<protocol value="igmp"/>` to `/etc/firewalld/zones/YOUR-ZONE`.
See also `man 5 firewalld.zone`.

For previous `firewall-cmd` versions without support for `--add-protocol=protocol`:

```shell
firewall-cmd --permanent \
             --zone=YOUR-ZONE \
             --add-rich-rule='rule protocol value="igmp" accept'

firewall-cmd --reload
```

This results in the following iptables/netfiler rule:

```
-A IN_YOUR-ZONE_allow -p igmp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```